# Is golden syrup with black around the edges bad?

Tags: storage-lifetime, syrup

I had a tin of golden syrup for a long time - longer than I care to admit. When I opened it up yesterday (to sweeten up some mulled wine), it was granular (a bit like honey can be), and black around the edges.

Is this 'bad', or just different?

Is the blackness the result of some chemical reaction with the tin?

And in general, does it eventually go off, or does it last indefinitely?

Comment: The black stuff is most likely the crystallised minerals from the sugar. It's normal, and occurs more often if you let the contents dry out

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Golden Syrup improves with age according to Heston Blumenthal's "In Search of Perfection". Here he analyses a 70 year old glass jar of Tate and Lyle Gold in the lab finding that the "older treacle contained the same flavour compounds as the normal stuff, but each was intensified".

In his recipe he fakes the ageing process by baking the tin at 70ºC (158ºF) for 24 hours noting that the flavour will continue to improve up to 100 hours.

Comment: +1 That validates my point that it **does not go off**.  Also, very interesting, as I always heat my tins in the oven before use with the lid ajar, so that the syrup becomes more fluid for ease of use.  Might inadvertently improve the end result!

Answer (score 4):

My favorite saying is *When in doubt throw it out*. Having said that you should throw that away. The black can either be from the oxidization of the tin or it could be mold growth. In either case golden syrup only has a shelf life of about two years; or one year after being opened, and it should be refrigerated after opening. The granulation could be *fixed* by reheating but the black is not worth the risk.

Comment: Black around the edges makes me wary, too.  Granulation is normal.

Comment: The black stuff is unlikely to be bacteria, as the extremely high sugar content is pretty antibacterial (the sugar tends to dry out the little beasties). It is susceptible to mold, however, so I'd still think you'd want to pitch it if it's discolored.

Comment: Well, it's all gone now, some in the bin, and some in the mulled wine. No untoward symptoms as yet :)

Comment: -1 NEVER refrigerate sugar products. They are perfectly persevered in...ummm...sugar. They have exceptionally long shelf lives if keep in a cool pantry, like tens of years!

Comment: Just wanted to add a bit of information: http://www.lylesgoldensyrup.com/faq.php The FAQ says not to use past the "Best Before" date.

Comment: To answer the question of whether to refirgerate sugar products. Yes you refrigerate sugar products. For more information please check out this article: http://www.survival-center.com/foodfaq/ff9-swee.htm And note that golden syrup is a Cane Syrup, and should be refrigerated after opening. Liquid sugar products are not chemically the same as granulated sugar products and can develop mold growth.

Comment: @Varuuknahl: No where on the Lyles tins does it say refridgerate and being from England where everyone tends to have the stuff, I can say I've never seen it refridgerated and people keep the stuff for years, opened, but resealed in tins in ambient cupboards and it is still fine.

Comment: @Varruknahl: Additionally - Lyles are bound to say not to use it past the best before date, as they have a vested interest in people buying more tins (and do not wish to be sued in a rare case).  *"When in doubt, throw it out"* is music to the ears of the business people, and deeply wasteful.

Comment: @Orbling - I am going to have to go with science on this one as mentioned in the above articles and the manufacturers website. Besides would you risk your kids health on a tin of something that costs less than 10 dollars, I wouldn't, it is not worth it.

Comment: @Varuuknahl: Even if it had really badly gone off, due to mould, corrosion, etc, the likelihood of the quantity involved harming anyone's health for more than a few hours would be negligible.  Also, $10!  I seem to remember it is all import in the US for this product.

Comment: Does anyone keep honey in the fridge? I'm no chemist, but the sugar content of honey and syrup must be comparable.

Answer (score 2):

Golden Syrup pretty much does not go off.  It is a blend of sugars and preserves as well, it should keep for many years.  It will crystallise slightly over time though that can usually be solved via warming.

Bacteria is highly unlikely, mould can form on it - that would be a reason to chuck it out, possibly not all of it.  The only serious issue is from the tin itself corroding, which is what the black area could be.  I've known households to use that stuff from a 20 year old tin and have no issues whatsoever.  It definitely does not need refrigerating any more than sugar does.

Comment: Unless you know someone is allergic to mold, it's usually safe just to scrape the mold off the top, and then clean the container.  This happens with maple syrup from time to time.

Comment: @Chris Cudmore: Aye, quite true.  I am allergic to mould myself, so am the special case.  But even I occasionally do such things if very careful.

Answer (score 1):

I've just thrown away an open tin of the syrup, as I thought it had a funny aftertaste. Still within the sell by, but open for about a year.

Answer (score 1):

Sweetheart, if you have doubts- just chuck it!
It's not worth a couple bucks to eat something that you think will could make you sick full stop.